# small and cheap embedded system

Tags: embedded-linux

for a home automation project I'm search for a small and cheap computer which is capable of running a small webservice. It should have the following features:

- Linux enabled (Debian, OpenWRT, ...)
- small form factor (ca. 4"x4" resp. 10cm x 10cm or below)
- chassis
- fanless
- low power (<5W)
- USB port(s)
- ethernet port
- opt. WiFi
- opt. Z-Wave or ZigBee
- min. 128MB RAM
- min. 256MB non volatile storage (NAND Flash, SD Card slot, ...)
- internal or external power supply
- available in EU, <100 EUR

There are plenty projects which need a small Linux box thus hopefully somebody has already found and used such an embedded computer.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic on all StackExchange sites, per the FAQ.

Comment: As are question about *any* home equipment and projects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can test a [Rasberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)